# Sequelizejs: findAll and count associations at the same time

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

say I have two models: `Post` and `Comment`, now I can use `Post.findAll()` to get all posts, but I also need the comment count of each post, I can make a loop and use `post.countComments()` to get the count, but is it possible to do that in one query? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sequelize subquery as field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286811/sequelize-subquery-as-field)

Comment: Another possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869077/how-to-count-a-group-by-query-in-nodejs-sequelize

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible with `findAndCountAll` method provided by the sequelize

Once you make a query by `Post.findAndCountAll({include: [{model: Comment, as: 'comments'}]})`

by doing `post.comments.length` you can get the count of comments of each post.

In case, if you would like to find the count of a single post use

`Post.findAndCount({where: {id: postId}}, include:[{model: Comments, as: 'comments'}]})`
which  returns `{count: <#comments>, rows: [<Post>]}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var attributes = Object.keys(Post.attributes);
var sequelize = Post.sequelize;

attributes.push([sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Comments" where "Comments"."postId" = "Post"."postId")'), 'commentsCount']);

var query = {
  attributes: attributes,
  include: [{model: Comment}]
}
Post.findAndCountAll(query)
  .then(function(posts){
    ...
  })
```